Are local martingales $M$ with $M - M_0 \ge 0$ almost surely constant?
Similarly to the theory of integration, conditional expectation can be developed for non-negative variables, without requiring integrability (e.g. Le Gall: Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes). So if we set aside concerns of integrability, we can easily prove with Fatou's Lemma, that if $M$ is a local martingale with $M_t - M_0 \ge 0$ for every $t \ge 0$, then $$\mathbb{E}[(M - M_0)_t | \mathbb{F}_s] \le (M - M_0)_s,$$
which is a necessary condition for being a super-martingale.
When I tried to check integrability, then I got the following:
$$\mathbb{E}[|(M - M_0)_t|] \stackrel{\text{non-neg}}= \mathbb{E}[(M - M_0)_t] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(M - M_0)_t| \mathbb{F}_0]] \le \mathbb{E}[(M - M_0)_0] = 0$$
from which it would follow that $M$ is almost surely constant. I feel like that I made a logical leap somewhere, but I couldn't figure out where. Any hints?

I think the statement is true.
I don't know if $M_0$ is a constant or a random variable, and I am not sure why the mention of conditional expectation.
Assuming $M_0$ is a constant, you have just shown $M_t$ is a local martingale with constant expectation, so a real martingale, with $\mathbb{E}[M_t]=M_0$ and $M_t \ge M_0$. From this you can quickly see that $M_t=M_0$ a.s.

$M$ being a local martingale there is an increasing sequence $(T_n)$ of stopping times with $\lim_nT_n=+\infty$ a.s. such that for each $n$, the stopped process
$$
M_{t\wedge T_n}\cdot 1_{\{T_n>0\}}
$$
is a martingale. But the expected value of a martingale is constant in time, so
$$
\Bbb E[M_{t\wedge T_n}; T_n>0]=\Bbb E[M_0; T_n>0]
$$
for each $n$ and each $t$. Combining this with the hypothesis that $M_t-M_0\ge 0$ for all $t$, a.s., we see that
$$
M_{t\wedge T_n}=M_0,\qquad \hbox{a.s. on }\{T_n>0\},
$$
first for each fixed $t\ge 0$, and then for all $t\ge0$ a.s., by right continuity of $M$. That is,
$$
M_t=M_0,\qquad\forall t\in[0,T_n], \hbox{ a.s. on }\{T_n>0\},
$$
for each $n$. Because $T_n\uparrow +\infty$ a.s., $\Bbb P[\cup_n\{T_n>0\}]=1$, and we arrive at
$$
M_t=M_0,\qquad\forall t\in[0,+\infty), \hbox{ a.s.}.
$$
